# CodeIgniter не срабатывает post

Tags: php, post, codeigniter

```
$('.add-cart').click(function () {
  var id = $(this).data('prodid');
  var data = {
    'addCartId' : id
  };
  var html = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=base_url()?>catalog",
    data: (data),
    dataType: "json"
  }).responseText;

  console.log(html);
});
```

мы получаем данные по товару и через POST отправляем. Вот код контроллера:

```
if ($this->input->post('addCartId')) {
    $data['cart'] = '4,9,5';
    $this->session->unset_userdata('cart');
    $this->session->set_userdata('cart', $data['cart']);
}
```

изначально положил в сессию строку "1,3,5", и, сколько бы я не выполнял post, данные сессии не меняются

Comment: в итоге проблема решилась достаточно глупо. Я просто сменил папку на денвере. Который постоянно разваливается по частям. Сменил потому что та папка перестала открываться денвером. Из всех папок в денвере теперь работает только subdomain.localhost. КААК я люблю денвер

Answer (score 0):

у меня ваш код работает
единственно может быть передаваемый параметр addCartId у вас имеет значение 0 или NULL или false
проверьте в консоли браузера какое значение передается

Comment: firebug говорит, что передается нужное значение